# How do I permanently disable wifi?

Tags: wireless

How do I delete my wifi driver or something else to permanently disable wifi?

I do not want to blacklist, or use security I want it deleted. I want to KEEP my wired networking.

Thanks

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE AS I WANT TO DELETE NOT DISABLE

Comment: This is not a duplicate as I do not want it to be disabled in bios. I want to delete the driver.

Comment: **There are no drivers in Ubuntu, only modules in the kernel...**  To disable a module, black-list it as in one of the answers.  The duplicate is to disable the wireless entirely...

Comment: It must be possible to delete the module in the kernel?

Comment: You need to build a custom kernel without that module. But it sounds like what you want to achieve is better done by disabling the module and restricting the user from enabling it again.

Answer (score 1):

I would disable it in BIOS if possible or remove the wifi card from the computer

Comment: I can not remove the wireless and I dont want it to be disabled, I want it to be deleted so that is can not be re-enabled. .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best method is to blacklist the driver because if you need to use it in the future you simply unblacklist it and you are back online.

Run this command and it will tell you the driver your device is using:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

then run:

```
echo "blacklist driver name" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

You put your devices driver name in the command were driver name is now.
To unblacklist the driver run:

```
 sudo sed 's/blacklist driver name//' -i /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

please note that your driver name will not have any spaces in it.

Comment: As I said I do not want to blacklist. I want to delete it so that it can not be undone.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell anything about your hardware, but both my Dell and Lenovo laptops have a physical switch to enable/disable wifi :) That would be the easiest way.

Comment: I can not remove the wifi and there is no hardware switch.

Answer (score 0):

On my HP laptop (granted, it's a business laptop and I don't think a lot of consumer laptops have the second option I'm about to tell you about) I can disable wifi with a hardware switch and even remove the wifi module through a hatch in the bottom of the laptop just like the hard drive and ram can be removed or changed.

Usually wifi also can be disabled in the bios settings, so look for this if you can't physically remove any module. If you disable wifi in the bios settings, the OS and any software running on the OS can't do anything about it.